# Same query works fine in a certain database but throws error in different database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch the year from 'MON-YY' format and then concatenating the fetched year with '01-JUN' . I used to_date to forcefully convert 'string' ('01-JUN-17') to 'date' type
The below code works fine in a particular database for eg db_1

```
select to_date('01-JUN-'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date('MAY-17','mon-yy'))) )  AS YEAR_START_DATE from dual;
```

returns :

```
01-JUN-17
```

But in db_2 the same code throws the below error :

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was      expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
       incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number   was
       required by the format model.
      *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure    the
       elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'01-JUN-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date('MAY-17','mon-yy'))
```

Will generate a string like `'01-JUN-2017'`

The problem occurs when you try to use `TO_DATE( datestring, format_model )` without specifying a format model. In this case the query will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

You can find the value for this using:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM   SYS.NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  PARAMETER - 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

If this does not match the format you specify then it will raise an exception.

You should explicitly specify the format model (and the language):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         '01-JUN-'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date('MAY-17','mon-yy','NLS_LANGUAGE="ENGLISH"')),
         'dd-MON-YYYY',
         'NLS_LANGUAGE="ENGLISH"'
       )  AS YEAR_START_DATE
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or you could use:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(
         TRUNC(
           TO_DATE( 'MAY-17', 'MON-YY', 'NLS_LANGUAGE="ENGLISH"' ),
           'YY'
         ),
         5
       ) AS YEAR_START_DATE
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: Hi MT0 .. Thanks for the reply ! You are correct ,I missed the format_model in code . So I tried out your first  piece of code ,and it returned value in db2 .But now as I ran my previous statement it is working fine in db2 .I am not sure about the issue .

Comment: I ran this query :select to_date(('01-JUN-'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date('MAY-17','mon-yy'))) )) AS YEAR_START_DATE from dual; and it returns 01-JUN-17 .

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a date format for your first to_date('01-JUN-'..) function. The date format for one database is probably DD-MON-YYYY but it could be DD-MM-YYYY in the other database.

After adding the date format your query looks like this:

```
select to_date('01-JUN-' || (extract(year from to_date('MAY-17', 'mon-yy'))),'DD-MON-YYYY') as year_start_date
  from dual;
```

It's good practise to always specify a format when converting dates from and to strings.

Comment: Hi Rene !!Thanks for the reply ! Do you mean NLS_DATE_FORMAT ? I checked NLS_DATE_FORMAT and its 'DD-MON-RR' for both the database .